# How to monitor events in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, events, firebug

For example I have a dropdown box and I want to see the javascript code that runs after clicking on that dropdown box. How to accomplish this?

The problem is that if I press button "break on next" it stops on hover event before I click on the item.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Right-click the element in the HTML tab, then click Log Events.

Comment: this logs the events, but how to stop on the click event like OP mentioned? or at least find the source javascript